# Selenium with Java and TestNG - Test login with Excel DataSheet

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Create 2 Classes (DataProviderWithExcel, ExcelUtils)  and export the login details (User Name, Password). But it skipped"Registration_data" in the "DataProviderWithExcel" Class.

**DataProviderWithExcel Class**

```
package practiceTestCases;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import utility.ExcelUtils;

public class DataProviderWithExcel {

    WebDriver driver;
    private String sTestCaseName;
    private int iTestCaseRow;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeMethod() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E://chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");     
    }

@Test(dataProvider="Authentication")
public void Registration_data(String sUserName,String sPassword)throws  Exception{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys(sUserName);
 System.out.println(sUserName);
 driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys(sPassword);
System.out.println(sPassword);
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
System.out.println(" Login Successfully, now it is the time to Log Off buddy.");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account_logout']/a")).click();
    }

@DataProvider()
public Object[][] Authentication() throws Exception{
     ExcelUtils.setExcelFile("E://My Work Place//Excel//src//testData//TestData.xlsx","Sheet1");
     sTestCaseName = this.toString();
      sTestCaseName = ExcelUtils.getTestCaseName(this.toString());
     iTestCaseRow = ExcelUtils.getRowContains(sTestCaseName,0);
    Object[][] testObjArray = ExcelUtils.getTableArray("E://My Work Place//Excel//src//testData//TestData.xlsx//TestData.xlsx","Sheet1",iTestCaseRow);
       return (testObjArray);
    }

@AfterClass
public void afterMethod() {
      driver.close();
    }
}
```

**ExcelUtils Class**

```
package utility;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelUtils {

    private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
    private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
    private static XSSFCell Cell;

public static void setExcelFile(String Path,String SheetName) throws Exception {
       try {
            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);
            ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
            ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
            } catch (Exception e){
                throw (e);
            }
    }

public static Object[][] getTableArray(String FilePath, String SheetName, int iTestCaseRow)    throws Exception
{   
   String[][] tabArray = null;
   try{
       FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
       ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
       ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
       int startCol = 1;
       int ci=0,cj=0;
       int totalRows = 1;
       int totalCols = 2;
       tabArray=new String[totalRows][totalCols];
          for (int j=startCol;j<=totalCols;j++, cj++)
           {
               tabArray[ci][cj]=getCellData(iTestCaseRow,j);
              System.out.println(tabArray[ci][cj]);
           }
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return(tabArray);
}

public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception{
   try{
      Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
      String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
      return CellData;
      }catch (Exception e){
        return"";
        }
    }

public static String getTestCaseName(String sTestCase)throws Exception{
    String value = sTestCase;
    try{
        int posi = value.indexOf("@");
        value = value.substring(0, posi);
        posi = value.lastIndexOf(".");    
        value = value.substring(posi + 1);
        return value;
            }catch (Exception e){
        throw (e);
                }
    }

public static int getRowContains(String sTestCaseName, int colNum) throws Exception{
    int i;
    try {
        int rowCount = ExcelUtils.getRowUsed();
        for ( i=0 ; i<rowCount; i++){
            if  (ExcelUtils.getCellData(i,colNum).equalsIgnoreCase(sTestCaseName)){
                break;
            }
        }
        return i;
            }catch (Exception e){
        throw(e);
        }
    }

public static int getRowUsed() throws Exception {
        try{
            int RowCount = ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum();
            return RowCount;
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw (e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
SKIPPED: Registration_data
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a jar file or its dependency, if you are using POM.xml then add the below dependencies to the POM file

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

If not then download poi.jar v3.9 and poi-ooxml v3.9 from Apache POI site and add it to the class path of the project

Comment: Before I execute the code I downloaded the jar files "poi-bin-3.10.1-20140818" from the 'http://poi.apache.org/download.html' site. And I added to the project. But it displays the above error.

Comment: Chamindi: there are total 9 jars in the bin folder which you have downloaded from Apache, can you tell me which one out of those have you added to the project classpath

Comment: poi-3.10.1-20140818,  poi-examples-3.10.1-20140818,  poi-excelant-3.10.1-20140818, poi-ooxml-3.10.1-20140818, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1-20140818, poi-scratchpad-3.10.1-20140818

Comment: Rishi, I added the other remaining 3 jars (dom4j-1.6.1, dom4j-1.6.1, xmlbeans-2.6.0 ) and it is working fine now. Thanks a lot

Comment: actually all the jar are not required in your project, though it will work with all the jars in the classpath but you will have to figure it out as to which jars are actually required to run your project :)