# The method setExcelFile(String, String) is undefined for the type ExcelUtils

Tags: java, selenium

```
// Declaring the path of the Excel file with the name of the Excel file
            String sPath = "E:\\Practice_space\\MyKDTTest\\src\\dataengine\\DataEngine.xlsx";

            // Here we are passing the Excel path and SheetName as arguments to connect with Excel file 
            ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(sPath, "TestSteps");
```

The above code i have mentioned in main class of java. I am calling the method setExcelFile which was already defined in the other class as bellow

```
public static void setExcelFile(String Path,String SheetName) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);
        ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
        ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
       }
```

But I am getting an error, please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that `setExcelFile` method is in class `ExcelUtils`?

Comment: Is that error something like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034994/selenium-with-java-and-testng-test-login-with-excel-datasheet

Comment: you can clear and rebuild your project to get rid off the issues.

Answer (score 1):

"Simple": the class `ExcelUtils` that the compiler is *seeing* when compiling the above code does **not** contain that method definition.

In other words: something in your setup is wrong. Such things can happen for example when you **change** the java source of a class - but you forget to compile that. Or you forget to re-build your JAR archive.

Long story short: there is some sort of inconsistency in your setup. As we don't have insight into that setup, that is all that can be said here!